# How to make a application interact with Hardware

Tags: networking, embedded

When I connect any mobile device or any other device to computer, Am I able to access it's root somehow? or interact using cmd for that using telnet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not normally.  Many mobile devices provide very limited functionality when connected to a computer (usually via USB).

In some cases they'll provide file system access to photos taken on the device.  In other cases they'll provide proprietary syncing with a vendor-provided application.

Some mobile devices like smartphones have development kits that allow you to add your own programs the device.  The [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), [BlackBerry SDK](http://developer.blackberry.com/), and [Xcode (Apple, iOS)](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) all allow this to varying extents.

There are also unofficial hacks that allow firmware replacement for more direct control of the device, but these can violate your warranty or potentially be malware.